# In which year and under which government was this video probably set?

Tags: history, meaning, music-video, pop-rock

Under which government, in what place, and in what year does [this video of Mongol Shuudan's "Finnish Knife"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNz2VMM-TV4) look like it's set?

I am not asking for an analysis of the song's lyrics because it looks like it doesn't really match the clip at all.

Answer (score 0):

The graffiti on the wall at the beginning of the video is basically "Lenin sucks"; there's Cyrillic everywhere; and the money in the bag is very stylized but has the double-headed imperial eagle of old Russian rubles or old Austrian crowns. [**edit:** OP stopped by to point out they are very probably [Russian rubles](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:250_Ruble_Note_1917_verso.jpg) from the [1917 Provisional Russian Gov't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Provisional_Government).] That said, the woman is done up in the flapper style of the 1920s after [**edit:** all three] of those empires had collapsed and their paper money rendered completely worthless.

So... basically an ahistorical mess roughly trying to be cool and mixing in US 1920s Prohibition gangster fashion with the similar chaos that was going on in Russia a few years earlier between the fall of Nicholas and the full establishment of the USSR. (Not that the early era of Communist rule was orderly or anything either, but no one was using imperial [**edit:** *or* provisional] paper money by that point.)

Comment: (Based on the song's name alone, of course, early independent Finland would be a good guess too with all of the Cyrillic just another aspect of the ahistorical messiness. The money doesn't match early Finnish marks either, though.)

Comment: The term "Finnish knife" is a term for the special type of knife (the one with sliding blade) in Russian. The money is obviously by Provisional government (as you can see, there is no crown).

Comment: That isn't obvious at all but [looks like you aren't wrong either](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:250_Ruble_Note_1917_verso.jpg).